# nohup and std::ignore() not working together

Tags: c++, linux, nohup

One way to wait for a RETURN keypress is to call std::ignore(). However, when I use nohup std::ignore() always returns immediately. Does there exist an alternative way to wait for a keypress, or just return that will work with nohup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `nohup` to run a command, it connects the standard input of your command to /dev/null so there's no way to wait for **any** kind of keypress.

When you attempt a read from /dev/null, it automatically responds with EOF.

I guess this could be checked using the following code (untested):

```
#include <unistd.h>
...
if (isatty(fileno(stdin))) ...
```

This should work, as the standard guarantees that `std::cin` is associated with stdin.

Comment: Yeah, but it shouldn't return. In my case it leads to an infinite loop. Note that the redirection of input happens only under linux.

Comment: That's what reading from /dev/null _does_ - return, instantly, with zero bytes read. Oh, and POSIX specifies nohup _may redirect standard input from an unspecified file_ if there's an associated terminal. Reading from it at all, on any platform, is probably fragile.

Comment: If it shouldn't return when the stream ends, what should it do? Block forever?

Comment: great, i'd like to avoid this from happening.

Comment: Well, detect whether stdin is a terminal (or provide a command-line option) and run in a non-interactive mode then.

Comment: It's really a question, what a console application working in the background could do with a keypress, probably nothing, hence the delay.

Answer (score 1):

> Does there exist an alternative way to wait for a keypress

*Where from*?

The keypress has to come from somewhere. You're expecting to get it from the controlling terminal, *and then you deliberately disconnected your process from that terminal*.

Yes, there exist alternatives:

1. don't disconnect from the terminal if you want to get input from there
2. get your keypress event from X instead, assuming you have a graphical environment running
3. create a new terminal and get your keypress from there. This probably means running an xterm in practise though, so it's not trivial.

> or just return that will work with nohup?

`std::ignore()` already *does* return, and you're complaining about that. Is waiting for a keypress the only thing that will work for you?

Comment: I have an Application class, that, for console applications, just did std::ignore() to wait for a RETURN, but this returned immediately, so an indefinite delay was the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with:

```
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::system_clock::duration::max());
```

Comment: So you just wanted to sleep forever? I never would have guessed that from the question.

Comment: reading from stdin will return immediately so the only thing to do is to wait indefinitely, I suppose.

Comment: I'm pointing out that you never said what you were trying to achieve, so no-one apart from you could guess what behaviour was better than returning immediately or why. This rather limits the potential quality of answers.